# CSS3 Width of two divs with muti-column layout , side-by-side

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have two divs, both with multi-column layout. I would like to have them side by side, but everything I try (like float) will mess all up.
I think the problem is that `width:auto;` is taking all the width.

I have made a jsfiddle to explain better: http://jsfiddle.net/2fPZ2/

The red and the violet divs should be in the same line.

The result has to be an horizontal layout, with section which are the red and the violet div.
Any suggestion?

Comment: The solution Vucko has written is good, but I need the red background (actually it will enlarge since there is space left)to fit the columns, because they have to be in a scrolling row.
Do you think is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `-webkit-column-count:2` to the `.container`.

**CSS**

```
.container{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    background:red;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fPZ2/2/).

More at : [column-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/column-count).

Comment: thanks, but column number is dynamic. It's part of a fluid layout.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is courtesy of Matthew James Taylor:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-2-column.htm